# how to do a keyword search in a list of java objects matched against all the members of the java object

Tags: java, search, collections

I have a `List<Employee>` which contains multiple members like id, name, designation, level, role, domain, account, etc.
I want to search a keyword against all the members of `Employee` in the entire list and return a list containing all matched instances `Employee`.

Here is a sample of my `Employee` class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String email { get; set; }
    public String designation{ get; set; }
    public String level { get; set; }
    public String domain { get; set; }
    public String role { get; set; }
}
```

More like a keyword search on any e-commerce website like Walmart or Amazon.

I don't want to write a series of if statements in a loop to match against each member. One way I think is to create another string that holds the concatenated value of each member in the `Employee` object and then uses Java 8 streams to do a  search but I think there would be a better way.
Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reflection` to loop through all fields and compare the values, so create this method in `Employee` class:

```
public class Employee{

/* Instance Members */

public boolean checkMatch(String keyword) throws IllegalAccessException {
    for(Field field: this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()){
        String value = (String) field.get(this);
        if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(keyword))
            return true;
    }
   return false;
}

}
```

USAGE:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    String keyword = "Research";
    employees.add(new Employee("john","john@doe.com","Manager","3rd","Research","Senior"));
    for(Employee e: employees){
        if(e.checkMatch(keyword)){
            System.out.println("Yayy! Record Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes in that case he can have checks, i just intended to provide an idea, taking care of all these things in example will just make it complex